# How to make tastypie give the url of a file instead of its path?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using Django and Tastypie to create a RESTful web app. I have a model like this

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    # some other fields
    image = models.ImageField('Image')
    def image_url(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Tastypie will give the image's path but actually I need its url. How to write a correct resource api to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default TastyPie is supposed to return URL of ImageField and FileField. 
See here: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py#L185

```
# Try to return the URL if it's a ``File``, falling back to the string
# itself if it's been overridden or is a default.
return getattr(value, 'url', value)
```

Please make sure that you are using the latest version of TastyPie.

Comment: I know why Tastypie returns the file's path now. The image field's url attribute returns the its path because my upload_to function returns a full path but not a relative path.

Comment: is it possible to disable this?