# An "image-serving web framework" in Python?

Tags: python, image, frameworks, webserver, static-files

I'm planning an iOS app that requires a server backend capable of efficiently serving image files and performing some dynamic operations based on the requests it gets (like reading and writing into a data store, such as Redis). I'm most comfortable with, and would thus prefer to write the backend in Python.

I've looked at a lot of Python web framework/server options, Flask, Bottle, static and Tornado among them. The common thread seems to be that either they support serving static files as a development-time convenience only, discouraging it in production, or are efficient static file servers but not really geared towards the dynamic framework-like side of things. This is not to say they couldn't function as the backend, but at a quick glance they all seem a bit awkward at it.

In short, I need a web framework that specializes in serving JPEGs instead of generating HTML. I'm pretty certain no such thing exists, but right now I'm hoping that someone could suggest a solution that works without bending the used Python applications in ways they are not meant for.

**Specifications and practical requirements**

The images I'd be serving to the clients live in the file system in a shallow directory hierarchy. The actual file names would be invisible to the clients. The server would essentially read the directory hierarchy at startup, assigning a numeric ID for each file, and would route the requests to controller methods that then actually serve the image files. Here are a few examples of ways the client would want to access the images in different circumstances:

1. Randomly (example URL path: `/image/random`)
2. Randomly, each file only once (`/image/random_unique`), produces some suitable non-200 HTTP status code when the files are exhausted
3. Sequentially in either direction (`/image/0`, `/image/1`, `/image/2` etc.)

and so on. In addition, there would be URL endpoints for things like ratings, image info and other metadata, some client-specific information as well (the client would "register" with the server, so that needs some logic, too). This data would live in a Redis datastore, most likely.

All in all, the backend needs to be good at serving image/jpeg and application/json (which it would also generate). The scalability and concurrency requirements are modest, at least to start with (this is not an App Store app, going for ad-hoc or enterprise distribution).

I don't want the app to rely on redirects. That is, I don't want a model where a request to a URL would return a redirect to another URL that is backed by, say, nginx as a separate static file server, leaving only the image selection logic for the Python backend. Instead, a request to a URL from the client should always return image/jpeg, with metadata in custom HTTP headers where necessary. I specify this because it is a way of avoiding serving static files from Python that I thought of, and someone else might think of too ;-)

Given this information, what sort of solution would you consider a good choice, and why? Or is this something for which I need to code non-trivial extensions to existing projects?

---

**EDIT**: I've been thinking about this a bit more. I don't want redirects due to the delay inherent in the multiple requests they entail, plus I'd like to abstract out the file names from the client, but I was wondering if something like this would be possible:

[image: A graph of the proposed request flow]

It's pretty self-explanatory, but the idea is that the Python program is given the request info by nginx (or whatever serves the role), mulls it over and then tells nginx to respond to the client's request with a specific file from the file system. It does so. The client is none the wiser about how the request was fulfilled, it just receives a response with the correct content type.

This would be pretty optimal in my view, but is it possible? If not with nginx, perhaps something else?

Comment: This is skirting the boundary of Stack Overflow and Server Fault. If mods wish me to take it to SF, lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Django for well over a year now, and it is the hammer I use for all my nails.  You could probably do this with a bit of database-image storage and django's builtin orm and url routing (with regex).  If you store the images in the database, you will automatically get the unique-id's set.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801379/how-can-i-use-redis-with-django) stackoverflow answer, you can use redis with django.

Answer (score 0):

`I don't want a model where a request to a URL would return a redirect to another URL that is backed by, say, nginx as a separate static file server, leaving only the image selection logic for the Python backend.`

I think Nginx for serving static and python for figuring out the image url is [the better solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn).

Still if you do not want to do that I would suggest you use any Python web framework (like Django) and write your `models` and convert them into `REST resources` (Eg. Using [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/)) and/or return a `base64` encoded image which you can then decode in your `iOS` client.

Refs:

[Decoding a Base64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/python-convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem)

[TastyPie returns the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153355/how-to-make-tastypie-give-the-url-of-a-file-instead-of-its-path) as default, you might have to do extra work to either store the image blob in the table or write more code to return a `base64` encoded image string

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at one of the async servers like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).